# Check that element is in DOM or not with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have quick and simple question. How can I check that an element is in the DOM or not?

For example how can I check if there is
`<p id="does_i_really_exist_or">this is just matrix</p>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ( $("#does_i_really_exist_or").length ) {
   //-- It does exist.
}
```

Comment: This is the way. You don't need to say > 0 like someone else said. Brock is right. any number great than 0 is truthy, and will be treated as true. 0 is the only thing that would be falsy. So, if the length is 0, then the length is falsy. Any other length besides 0 is truthy. Unless we really were in the matrix and you could have a negative length, then you would need to check if it were greater than zero. Otherwise, do what Brock says.

Comment: I know that.. its for the sake of clarity.. I would prefer the boolean result there

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($("#does_i_really_exist_or").length > 0) {

   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here are three different ways:

```
if ($("#does_i_really_exist_or").length > 0) {

   // do something
}

if ($("#does_i_really_exist_or").size() > 0) {

   // do something
}

if ($("#does_i_really_exist_or")[0]) {

   // do something
}
```