# Determine if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check that element is in DOM or not with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119308/check-that-element-is-in-dom-or-not-with-jquery)

So I have a function, that serves to navigate up two levels with `.parent().parent()`, then it moves to the next node in the document with `.next()` and finally grabs the attribute I need from a nested a with `.find('a').attr('data-record-id')` and that's all fine and dandy, but now I need to find if the `<a></a>` element even exists, if not I need to hide the header relating to it. A mockup of the layout is as such:

```
<html>
    <head><title>My Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <h4 class="dragable">2012-08-20<span style='display: none'><a class='delete-btn'></a></span></h4>
        <ul>
           <li>
             <div>
                 <div>
                    <a data-record-id="9">97 bpm</a>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </li>
         </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
```

So given that layout what's the best way to determine if the `<a></a>` element exitst, if not, then hide/delte the h4 class relating to it.

Comment: @MattBall That is right, however there is a infinitely small overhead on calling multiple methods on an empty jQuery object, and OP seems to want to do something when the element is not present in the DOM thus the check has a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(selector).find('a')` is returning an array, no matter if a exists or not. You can easily test with `$(select).find('a').length (or .size() )`. How this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `length`

```
if($next.find('a').length > 0)
```

Comment: At least this almost-explains how the `.length` check works. No elements == .length==0 == falsy value. Integer different than 0 evaluates as a truthy value. That makes the `> 0` superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `length` property to determine if the element exists:

```
if ($(body).find('a[data-record-id]').length) {
    // element exists
} else {
    // element does not exist
}
```