# Jquery span:contains doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i need to enable a div only if a span has certain text, yet the div gets enabled no matter what i put in the "contains" brackets. Even random gibberish. 
In my page's head I reference google's jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then run my script right before the closing body tag

```
<script>
if($("span:contains('abc123')")){
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check that element is in DOM or not with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119308/check-that-element-is-in-dom-or-not-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like below:

```
<script>
if($("span:contains('abc123')").length > 0){
$("#mydiv").css("display","block")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the element actually exists. A selector will always return a truthy value. The `length` property will tell you how many of those elements there are in the collection, if any:

```
if( $("span:contains('abc123')").length ) { 
  //^^ elements exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I believe this is already answered, but just to add on:

```
if( $("span:contains('abc123')").length ) { 
  $("#mydiv").show();
}
```

I think this works better, since you already have jQuery on the page.